# google SA 360: where do I get the clickId

Tags: google-sa360-api

According to this page:

https://developers.google.com/search-ads/v2/how-tos/conversions/insert#json

We can send a POST to https://www.googleapis.com/doubleclicksearch/v2/conversion

with the following data:

```
{
 "kind": "doubleclicksearch#conversionList",
  "conversion" : [{
    "clickId" : "COiYmPDTv7kCFcP0KgodOzQAAA", // Replace with a click ID from your site
    "conversionId" : "test_20130906_04",
    "conversionTimestamp" : "1378710000000",
    "segmentationType" : "FLOODLIGHT",
    "segmentationName" : "Test",
    "type": "TRANSACTION",
    "revenueMicros": "10000000", // 10 million revenueMicros is equivalent to $10 of revenue
    "currencyCode": "USD"
  }]
}
```

The question is, where do we get the clickId?

We have access to https://campaignmanager.google.com/ This has:

1. siteId
2. placementId
3. adId

Is it any of those?

Answer (score 0):

ok, clickId turns out to be the gclid url parameter which google sends when the user first clicks on an advert. You have to record it against that user when he goes onto to register, then pass it in these offline conversion calls.